# Getting lists to sit beside each other

Tags: css

I'm trying to get four lists to sit beside each other to the right of `#intro`. I've tried making them `display:inline-block;`

http://jsfiddle.net/7aq8cx4o/

```
#profile { width:75%; float:right; position:relative;}
```

[image]

Comment: Your `#intro` div has a width of 35%, while the `#profile` div is 75%. Since that's greater than 100%, they *can't* float next to each other.

Comment: Someone may have time to answer the whole question, but the first issue is that `#intro` has a width of `35%` and `#profile` has a width of `75%`. Since that's `110%`, you will have to change one of them so the total is `100%`

Comment: @PaulRoub In at the same time :)

Comment: lol how derpy of me. I swore I read that 35% as 25%. :p

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Agreed with Paul Roub and Disnifor comments.
I've also noticed that the width exceeds the 100% and easy fixed it by `#intro { width:25%; ... }`

check this code here:
http://codepen.io/anon/pen/dogPrw?editors=110

cheers,
(and credit again to Paul and Disnifor who answered before me in comments)